# How can I emulate this color loop effect?

Tags: after-effects

The title of this question isn't great at explaining what I want to do, so have this gif of the effect I want to emulate: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OCxA.gif (quality of the gif is shite, ik, please bear with me)

I think I need to use the LoopOut() expression for well, the loop, but I don't know how to animate the colors like that. Do I assign different colors in a shape? I'm fairly new to motion graphics, so I'm not familiar with technical terms and all that. Any help/guidance is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following:

- Create the square shape you are looking for, as a shape layer with a stroke and no fill
- Duplicate the shape layer, for example, 4 times
- Apply the Trim Paths effect to these layers and distribute it as you wish (for example, if using 4 layers first one from 0 to 25, second one from 25 to 50, third 50 to 75 and fourth one 75 to 100%.
- Set a different color for each layer
- Create a new Null Object and assign the Slider Control effect to it
- Set the Trim Paths Offset property to be driven by the Slider property of the Slider Control (using the pick whip from each layer)
- Animating the Slider property of the Slider control in the Null Object, driving the color of all the sides.
- Use masks to fix the possible glitches on the vertices and to make it look nice
- you can then alt-click on the stopwatch of the Slider property inside the Slider Control of the Null Object and type LoopOut(). Make sure that the first and last keyframes are correct so once the looping is activated the end is the same as the beginning and you should be good to go!

I think this should more or less point you in a possible way of solving it, let me know if you need more help!

Answer (score 0):

In Illustrator, draw a square with a stroke, no fill, and rotate it 45 degrees. And on a separate layer, draw 6 triangles in the desired colours. Example below:

[image: Illustrator artwork and layers panel]

Save as an AI file. Import this artwork into After Effects, setting Import Kind to *Composition*.

Set the composition length to 4 seconds.

[image: After Effects layers panel]

Set the track matte for the triangles layer to the Alpha Matte of the square layer. (#1 in the above)

Open the rotation property of triangles, set a key frame on frame 1, then go to 4 seconds, and set a key frame of 1 rotation. (#2 in the above)

Precompose these layers, then apply a CC Light Burst 2.5 effect for the glow.

Result is as below.

[image: resulting animation]